# Can't get past splash screen on 13.10 boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, display, gui

I have just updated to 13.10.  The system boots and loads, and the GUI login screen appears.  After logging in, however, I am left with the colorful splash screen and nothing else happens.  I can use ctl-alt-F1 to get to a terminal login, but I don't know how to analyze this problem or to converge on a solution.  Together with the Ubuntu upgrade, I installed a graphics card...Radeon R7 260X.  According to the AMD site, there is a Linux driver for this card, but I don't know how to install it, and I don't even know if that is the problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Antonio for your suggestions.  I "cat"ed the log file but found no errors there.  In a terminal session I installed jockey-common and then ran jockey-text -l.  The results are:

Comment: Oops...sent the comment too fast.  The results of the jockey-text -l query are "kmode: fglrx -ATI, Fire GL (Proprietary, Enabled, In use.) kmode: fglrx_updates - Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in Use)

Comment: The GUI login screen appears and I can type my login name and password in the GUI environment.  The problem occurs AFTER that...the splash screen remain but all text and icons constituting the desktop never appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should try logging in a terminal session (Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to it) and read the content of /var/log/Xorg.0.log to get some more clue regarding your problem.

Also, once you get to the terminal session install the package jockey-common and then run `jockey-text -l` to get a list of the available drivers and the one that's been used.